# How to add UTF-8 support to PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8

How do I add UTF-8 support to this PHP file? This way the text is garbled.
I tried adding some code I found online but it didn't work...

This is my original code. Question is what to add there for UTF-8 support.

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/

$webmaster_email = "natalie@cakery.co.il";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "contact.html";
$error_page = "thanks.html";
$thankyou_page = "thanks.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$Name1 = $_REQUEST['Name1'] ;
$Name2 = $_REQUEST['Name2'] ;
$Phone = $_REQUEST['Phone'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
  $comments, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: "Support" in what form exactly? You mean the regex?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I couldn't figure out a solution out of this. All I want is a form to be filled in with UTF-8 encoding, and when received - viewed properly (and not garbeled).

Answer (score 4):

You want to send an UTF8 compliant email, then I *think* you might try and UTF8 encode your `$comments` before sending the email:

```
$comments = utf8_encode($comments);
```

But this **isn't guaranteed to work** because it all depends on how your application (and specifically the part gathering those comments) is working, what encoding it is already using, and how `$comments` itself is built.

`utf8_encode` (and my suggestion) operates on the **assumption** that the reason you're seeing "garbled characters" is that you're actually sending Latin1 encoding under the guise of UTF-8; but your problem might be different, and without having a look at `$comments` (best of all, at a *hex dump* of `$comments`), a guess is the best anyone can do.

Another possibility (exactly opposite) is that you're sending unadvertised UTF8 to somebody who decodes it as ISO-8859-15. In that case you should properly advertise the content type *instead* of re-encoding the content, adding the [proper extra headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to `mail()` function.

I recommend deceze's links, even if the second might look as it classifies my suggestion among the "false promises" :-)

### Update

Okay, so let's say that running

```
$Name1 = $_REQUEST['Name1'];
```

gets you strange characters. The above comes from some form; you need to check the encoding of the page displaying that form. Let's say that you have put in the "Name1" field the value "Léon". Then if you add, above, the instruction

```
die(bin2hex($Name1));
```

the receiving page ought to terminate and display a hex string. If the name was correctly received in UTF8, it ought to say `4cc3a96f6e`. But if you're running ISO-8859-15, you will see `4ce96f6e`, and that means that you need to either change the encoding of the transmitting form (so that it transmits good UTF8) or you have to `utf8_encode` the input:

```
$Name1 = utf8_encode($_REQUEST['Name1']);
```

Of course you might also receive stranger hex codes: `4c826f6e`, maybe.

In case you receive `4cc3a96f6e` *and yet it still does not work*, the problem is **not** in the transmitting form or the receiving PHP but later. For example when you display the string. *That* page might be in ISO-8859-15 encoding, and outputting good UTF8 will not work. If that it the case, you ought to change the advertised encoding of the output page, by supplying

```
Header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

If the other text in that page appears broken, this means that the page has been edited by a ISO-8859-15 editor; so it contains ISO-8859-15 special characters, that you see correctly with the ISO encoding, but no more when shifting to UTF-8. In that case you need to convert the file before everything else, and use an UTF editor from now on.

Comment: Erm, I don't know how to do that. The code looks different here: $Name1 = $_REQUEST['Name1'] ;
$Name2 = $_REQUEST['Name2'] ;
$Phone = $_REQUEST['Phone'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;